# Sandcastle setup - Navigation to webpage was canceled

Tags: c#, documentation-generation, sandcastle, helpfile

I am try to use Sandcastle Help File Builder, but can't quite get it to work. Here is what I have done:

1) installed the program; works like normal

2) enabled xml in the project I want documentation for that gets generated in the /bin

3) created a new sandcastle help file project

4) added the C# project as (its a WCF service in case that matters) a documentation service

5) ran the "build" to generate the help file

6) went to "documentation"/"view help file"/"view help file" in the GUI

7) The file opens and contains the appopriate "folders", but every page says "Navigation to the webpage was canceled"

I have seen the xml file in the /bin and it contains all of my /// comments, so why are they not showing up in the help file? Any ideas?

Comment: if you right click on the help file, choose "Properties", do you have a button to "unblock content"? (on the General Tab)

Comment: I put together a small tutorial showing how to install sandcastle, sandcastle help file builder, and get it to build documentation when visual studio builds your project in release mode. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211693/generate-html-documentation-automatically-during-a-build-with-sandcastle/5200822#5200822 I'm not sure if that will help you at all, but you can verify your process with the one I describe and see if something is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you try to open a *.chm file from a different drive than C:\ (main windows drive) ?
If so; try copy the file to c:\ and try to open it again.

Another possible cause is that the chm file is blocked. Go to the properties of the *.chm file and click [unblock].

Comment: I had the .chm on a public drive. Worked like a charm once I switched it over to my C:\\.