# How do you know which project in Visual Studio builds very last?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build, sandcastle

I am building sandcastle documentation as per this answer: [Generate html documentation automatically during a build with Sandcastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211693/generate-html-documentation-automatically-during-a-build-with-sandcastle/5200822#5200822) and I need to know which project in my solution builds very last. I'm sure I'm missing something very simple. Is there an easy way to know what order my projects are building?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at Project -> Project Build Order?

Comment: Why don't Microsoft have simple names for things? The simplicity of their software is often crippled by their archaic text...

Comment: @dot I guess that was sarcasm? :)

Comment: Yeah. I'm in a strange mood today!

Comment: Nope. Hadn't looked there. Thank you! I knew it was something simple. Sorry for the dumb question.